# callbacks passed from another class

Tags: haxe

How do you get callbacks running in haxe 3 that are passed by another class?

I'm trying to pass a callback function to a class, but I'm getting an error

```
public static var onFocusCallback:Dynamic;

public static function triggerFocus():Void
{
    onFocusCallback.bind();
}
```

the error I get is
`[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property bind not found on builtin.as$0.MethodClosure and there is no default value.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try not to use `Dynamic` if possible. It can trigger weird errors like that one.

The way to use a callback is like this http://try.haxe.org/#60f45

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        onFocusCallback = function() {
            trace("focus");
        }   
        triggerFocus();
    }

    // Try not to use Dynamic
    //public static var onFocusCallback:Dynamic;
    // If you don't know the type of the function, you can use this:
    //public static var onFocusCallback:haxe.Constraints.Function;
    // But it's always better to give a concrete type like:
    public static var onFocusCallback:Void->Void;


    public static function triggerFocus():Void
    {
        if(onFocusCallback != null) onFocusCallback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, I did try that initially, my problem was in defining the variable. I used `public static var onFocusCallback:Function;`

Comment: @Daniel, you can also define a default implementation with the [`dynamic` access modifier](http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-dynamic.html): `public static dynamic function onFocusCallback() { throw "Not implemented yet, reassign first"; }` ([example](http://try.haxe.org/#A9459))

Answer (score -1):

the other solution I got to work, within minutes of posting question, was to use `Reflect`

```
Reflect.callMethod(null, onFocusCallback, []);
```

Comment: While this also may work, I also would recommend to dont use reflection that much, because dead-code-elimination (DCE) can not freely do its job. Sometimes if you use DCE full, then you manually have to mark classes/fields with `@:keep` to prevent them from being eliminated. Using `Void->Void` instead of Dynamic in your case should already solve the issue.

Comment: There's no need to use `Reflect`.  You can simply *try* to call a dynamically typed variable: `onFocusCallback();` ([example](http://try.haxe.org/#630bd)).  However, this will give runtime errors that you should handle if `onFocusCallback` is not _yet_ a function (if it's null or anything else that can't be called)...  The typed solution by Justo Delgado is better.